# Multiple criteria in a lookup formula--conditional lookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, vba

I have data of the following table format:
[image: Original Data Set]

As you can see I have a few descriptor columns (view ID, Region View ID, Client ID, Display Name, etc), with one incorrect column (wrong_threshold).

I'd like to "correct" Display name and Wrong Threshold using criteria from the following table:
[image: Criteria for Correction]

Corrected Display name is based on all of the other criteria except for threshold.

Threshold is corrected based on all criteria.

My problem is that if this were simpler I would do a lookup using an array formula.
However there is so many criteria to select from here I am not sure that would work.  Any suggestions on this would be appreciated please.

Edit: so lets say that i have in my dataset (picture 1, above), a displayName of "Refresh". It has the RVID of InvoiceHomeFlow/InvoiceHomePF, VID of /Invoiceworkbench, component Type me.xyz.RichCommandImageLink, an action type 'Action', and Click Type 'Query'. This maps to the second row's criteria of the second image, above. My dataset then needs to be updated to have '2000' as the "Corrected Threshold" and a "Final Display Name" of 'Landing Page Region Refresh'.

Comment: so can you give an example? what do you expect to achieve? an example please

Comment: Sure, so lets say that i have in my dataset (picture 1, above), a displayName of "Refresh".  It has the RVID of InvoiceHomeFlow/InvoiceHomePF, VID of /Invoiceworkbench, component Type me.xyz.RichCommandImageLink, an action type 'Action', and Click Type 'Query'.  This maps to the second row's criteria of the second image, above.  My dataset then needs to be updated to have '2000' as the "Corrected Threshold" and a "Final Display Name" of 'Landing Page Region Refresh'.

Answer (score 2):

A shortcut I often use when looking up on multiple criteria is to add a dummy column to each table that just concatenates the variables you want to look up on. Then you just do an index match (or vlookup) on this concatenated column.

Comment: that might work! using array lookups it for some reason fails if you give it more than 2 columns to match